# FacialFeatures not working with high quality picture

Tags: image-processing

I have the following picture (1280x720, png) on which I want to detect the Facial Features:

```
FacialFeatures[pic,"Landmarks"]
```

But it is returning an empty result. It works with other pictures where there is less from the face visible however, that's why I don't understand what is happening. Maybe it is a problem specific to my computer, so I was wondering if someone can reproduce this result? My Mathematica version is 12.1.1.0.

[image]

Comment: I'm not surprised because functions that use machine learning tend to be somewhat robust on images that look like the ones they trained on, and not good at all for other images...

Comment: Maybe you need a whole face.  It seems to work fairly well on my photos.

Comment: The imaging team needs to it step up here

Comment: So when you guys use this image, it also doesn't work? That is strange :(

Comment: Again, I don't think it's strange. If you want to have a better understanding about how the net is trained, what the dataset looks like etc. you can have a look [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/2D-Face-Alignment-Net-Trained-on-300W-Large-Pose-Data). See the example of robustness to facial crop size. Your is the opposite to the example in that it's a more closely cropped image. It's also noteworthy that the ears have been blurred and other features have been enhanced in your image.

Comment: You need to specify the face box manually then, because that's what it's having trouble finding: Try this `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRB5.png"];
rect = Rectangle[{250, 50}, {1000, 700}];
HighlightImage[img, rect]
results=FacialFeatures[img, "Landmarks", Method -> "FaceBoxes" -> rect]` and it will return the results. They are messy though: `HighlightImage[img, Flatten[Values[results], 1]]`